# New ubuntu 20.04 computer is stuck in a black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: boot, 20.04

I’m very new to linux and I recently acquired a Desktop with linux mint and decided to install Ubuntu on it just so I could learn how, and to get myself more familiar with how linux works. It was working fine until I installed a wifi card and now it won’t boot(it goes through the UEFI and BIOS thing then gets stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor). Im using Ubuntu 20.04 and one of the solutions i found was to press  alt+ctrl+f2 and enter my login but once I enter the username and the password prompt shows up the keyboard won’t type. Anyone who has a solution keep in mind I know next to nothing about linux operating systems, but I know a bit about computers in general.

one of the things I had to do to install the wifi card was unplug one of the USB cords from the motherboard. I really don't know if that means anything but I figured I'd mention it incase.

Comment: Your password field on a text terminal doesn't show any "*" or other characters as you type, as it's more secure that way. Should someone be watching you, they cannot count the "*"'s that appear on screen (groups of 3-dots were tried but are as easily counted; even though end-users do like seeing some feedback, it's more secure without anything showing).  Your correct password should work when entered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying it goes through uefi and bios. Does it not go through GRUB?
Check if UBUNTU is installed correctly. Yes,the keyboard only visually doesn't types the password but the password is being typed there in the text field.
This is for super safety if some Salmon fish is watching your screen.
Try removing the WiFi card and check again.